# Open default Image Viewer

Tags: android, image

I have displayed a set of images in the list view, when I click one list item image, that specific image have to open in the default **Image Viewer**.

When the click is made i taken that specific image and displayed in the imageview but for addition facilities like zoom all i have to open that Bitmap image in the default Image Viewer in android.

Can any one tell me possible answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In listview on itemclick u just add this .

```
            File file = new File(itemList.get(position));
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri data = Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath());
            intent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```

in itemlist is your arraylist.

Comment: see here and try this so simply u can see image in android default gallery.

Comment: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/sdcard/JJ Camera/IMG_08-Mar-2016 05:41:40 pm.jpg typ=image/* }` this is the error I am getting i have edited as you mentioned

Comment: can you add permission in your mainfest ?

Comment: no i didn't add permission. but its working thanks a lot. But when i click that it asking which application to open like Album, Photos, PicsArt. How can i view the image without asking these permission

Comment: action_view give that its depend on api level in which api you test.i have use that code in my app.i test in api level 19 its directly open in gallery.

Comment: I am also testing in Api level 19 only but it asking options

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105763/discussion-between-kishan-and-vanitha).

Answer (score 2):

By using this you can open default **Image Viewer**

```
Intent viewImageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(viewImageIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save bitmap to file and show image this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + filepath), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how do I use Bitmap data to view image?

Comment: u have store image in arraylist ?